# Filecoin Textileio Powergate Not Enough Miners from Reputation Module to Satisfy The Constraints Error

Tags: docker, blockchain, ipfs, filecoin

I am running WSL Ubuntu 20.04 (Version 2 with Docker Desktop Support) within Windows 10 Pro Version 21H1

The steps are as follows:

1. `git clone https://github.com/textileio/powergate.git`
2. `cd powergate/`
3. `cd docker/`
4. `nano docker-compose.yaml` where I added "["lotus", "daemon", "--import-snapshot", "https://fil-chain-snapshots-fallback.s3.amazonaws.com/mainnet/minimal_finality_stateroots_latest.car"]" between lines 32 and 33.
5. `make up`
6. Waited for the node to finish importing and then syncing.
7. `^C` then `make down` then deleted the line "["lotus", "daemon", "--import-snapshot", "https://fil-chain-snapshots-fallback.s3.amazonaws.com/mainnet/minimal_finality_stateroots_latest.car"]" from docker-compose.yaml
8. `make up`
9. Now that the node was running I typed `cd ..` so I was in the repo's root directory, then `make install-pow`
10. with the `pow` command in my GOPATH I typed `pow` to make sure pow was linked fine to `powd`. It was.
11. `pow admin users create`
12. copied the token and ran `export POW_TOKEN=<token copied to here>`
13. Then `pow wallet addrs` and funded the address
14. I went to the directory behind the folder of my static website which is about 5GB in size.
15. I typed `pow data stage <my-static-site-folder>`
16. After it was finished staging and printed out the CID I typed `pow config apply --watch <CID` waited a long time while it said the job was executing and then I got...

```
---------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------+-------+--------------
             <job id here>             | JOB_STATUS_FAILED executing    |       |       |
                                       | cold-storage config: making    |       |       |
                                       | deal configs: getting miners   |       |       |
                                       | from minerselector: getting    |       |       |
                                       | miners from reputation         |       |       |
                                       | module: not enough miners from |       |       |
                                       | reputation module to satisfy   |       |       |
                                       | the constraints                |       |       |
```

I don't understand what the problem is. I repeated the `pow config apply --watch <CID` command each time adding the --override flag with several different modifications to a custom config file. The content did appear briefly on IPFS (not Filecoin), but after I continued running the config apply command the site went down from IPFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be fixed by adding miners to the "trustedMiner" entry in the config file because `pow` doesn't necessary detect miners that fit your specs.

I went to a Filecoin miner info aggregation site (I used "https://filrep.io/") and added miners to the `trustedMiner` section of the config file used in the apply command to start a Filecoin deal.

For example the "trustedMiners" line in your config file should look like this:

```
"trustedMiners":  ["<Miner Id>", "<Miner Id>","<Miner Id>", "<Miner Id>", ...],
```

with however many miners you want to add.

Then you would execute the command:
`pow config apply --watch <CID> -o -c new-config-file.json`

Btw the `--watch` flag is optional as it just allows you to see the status of the deal in real time.